# Search JavaDoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, javadoc

Is there a way to search in javadoc comments only (via Eclipse)?
I just want to find text within a javadoc comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use **Eclipse File Search dialog** for all *.java* files and use this regular expression as input:

```
"(?s:/\*\*([^\*]|\*[^/])*?###INPUT###.*?\*/)"
```

and replace the ###INPUT### with what you are searching for.

See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689354/regex-for-matching-javadoc-fragments) about this regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the javadoc is in source files that are in your workspace then you can use 'File Search'.