# Regex for matching javadoc fragments

Tags: java, regex, javadoc

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689007/search-javadoc-in-eclipse) got me thinking in a **regex** for matching *javadoc* comments that include some specified text.

For example, finding all *javadoc* fragments that include `@deprecated`:

```
/**
* Method1
* .....
* @deprecated
* @return
*/
```

I manage to get to the expression `/\*\*.*?@deprecated.*?\*/` but this fails in some cases like:

```
/**
* Method1
* .....
* @return
*/
public int Method1() { } 

// this method should be @deprecated
public void Method2() { }    

/**
* Method3
* .....
* @return
*/
public int Method3() { }
```

where it matches all the code from the 1st *javadoc* fragment until the 3rd *javadoc* fragment.

Can someone give a **regex** for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one :

```
/\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!/))*?@deprecated.*?\*/
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Thanks.

Comment: I would use (?!/) instead of [^/]. Otherwise it won't match if the space before the "@" is missing, ie, "*@deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

method2() does not have a javadoc comment and is therefor not deprecated (though the comment states it should be).

Also, if you want to extract information from the javadoc comments I’d recommend looking into the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html) tool and writing a [Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec/com/sun/javadoc/Doclet.html). You have easy access to all the information from the javadoc comment from there.

Comment: Bombe, I just chose the string "@deprecated" as I might have chosen "bla". That is not the point. Also, I cannot use an external tool because this expression is to incorporate in the eclipse search dialog. See the related question.