# Regex to match javadoc style comments

Tags: php, ruby, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex for matching javadoc fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689354/regex-for-matching-javadoc-fragments)

I have files having content like

```
/**
 * Some Content
 * @param ..
 * @author ..
 *
 */
function a_sample_function ( $args = '' ) {
```

I need to extract the text

```
Some Content
@param ..
@author ..
```

given a function name a_sample_function ( the `*` can be removed by a `gsub` later I believe)

I'm writing this in ruby.

Comment: PHP actually provides a way for extracting DocBlock comments using the Reflection API.  I know you're writing a utility in Ruby, but maybe it would be worthwhile to have a PHP script to use as a bridge for extracting these comments?

See: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php (there's a similar API for functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with the help of [Regex for matching javadoc fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689354/regex-for-matching-javadoc-fragments)
Thanks!