# Regex for all ocurrences on Java Commented Lines (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, regex-greedy

I need to replace all occurrences of `abc` with `xyz`, but only if they occur in Javadoc comments.

I am using Eclipse.

I believe requiring simply that the line starts either with `\s*\*` or `\s/\*` *should* be sufficient for my purposes (no need to match for "occurs between `/**` and `*/`", but that would work fine too).

I tried using: `(\s\*|\s/\*)(.*)abc` and replacing with `$1$2xyz` but the problem is that the regex is greedy so it gives me only the longest line that matches my string (i.e., I can only replace the *last* `abc` on any given line). Is there any way to ask it for *all* the possibilities, or is that outside of the scope of (non-recursive) regular expressions?

If it is outside the scope, would a recursive expression work? (Which Eclipse does not support in any case).

Comment: Did you go through a fine answer already written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689007/search-javadoc-in-eclipse) ?

Comment: I don't think you understood my needs. That answer finds the *entire comment*. I need a way to be able to essentially be able press 'find' twice and find each one  in turn so that I can just press 'replace all' once and get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible. A regex traverses each character of the input text once and it can't go back.

You can either match on the first abc or the last abc of a JavaDoc line, because by the time it has matched on either of them, the characters defining that line as a JavaDoc comment can't be matched again.

Comment: Ah ok. I worried it would be like that. I'll just build a Python script or something. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Does saying "your issue does not have a solution" count as "solved"?

By the way, in the end I just checked and saw that "abc" wasn't being used outside of comments in any case, so I just find/replaced them.

Comment: @MarkChimes Well, you were asking if there is a way to do so, indicating a "Yes" or "No" answer.